# Commands in Dockerfile has no effect in container (Docker)

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am deploying dockerized application to digitalocean server. (Ubuntu 22.04)
But I don't want to pass vendor directory there. To create it in remote server I am trying to use `composer update` method in my application's container.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm as php

USER root
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install PHP packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libreoffice \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer update
RUN composer dump-autoload

RUN chmod -R 755 storage/

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

When I run docker build and up commands everything working fine without any error. But my application throws an error because it can't find `vendor` directory in application.

As you see in `Dockerfile` I am running `composer update` command. It is working while building and gives me some logs:

[image]

But when I log in my container with `docker exec -it app /bin/bash` command, I can't see any vendor directory created in `/var/www`. I am able to run `composer update` in container manually and it is not giving any error.

Main problem is why `composer update` is not creating `vendor` directory while givings logs. Even `RUN chmod -R 755 storage/` command is not giving defined permissions to folder. I feel like `Dockerfile` has no effect on my container except installing packages and extensions.

Comment: You set a volume like `- ./:/var/www` so I am not sure what happens in this situation. I would think it would modify your local file system (i.e. the host) but it may not have permission to do so.

Comment: @apokryfos How it can change the local file system (i.e. the host) ? I am running `composer update` in container, so container doesn't have any connection with my local file system.

Comment: `- ./:/var/www` connects your host filesystem to the container filesystem i.e. `./` in the host will appear as `/var/www` in the filesystem. This is not a copy of the host filesystem, **it is** the host filesystem

Comment: Till know I was thinking it is copy of host. Then if I change something in `/var/www`, it will try to change my host as well? In this situation I should actually run `composer update` before `COPY . /var/www` command

Comment: I am not sure whether `COPY . /var/www` will have any effect in your case because `/var/www` is your local filesystem so it should not be necessary. You can try running `composer update` in the host instead and removing it from your Dockerfile, alternatevely you can remove the volume completely but it will make development harder. If this is for a production image you should definately remove the volume

Comment: When you map a volume to `/var/www` you hide everything in that directory in the image and replace it with the volume content.

Comment: @apokryfos I removed `volume` and rebuilt again. But still command are not affecting anything. I am trying any command like `mkdir tmp`, `composer update`, `chmod 777 /storage` but none of them looks like working. I can do all of them in container but not in `Dockerfile`

Comment: with docker-compose try running `docker-compose down --volumes` to make sure the previously created volumes are removed